# What are the consequences of leaving the UK with Rent Arrears accumulating?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

I was unable to cancel my tenancy agreement after I cancelled my plans to study in the UK. This has resulted in me owing them annual rent. I agree it’s my fault but the amount is significantly high and I cannot afford to pay that amount while staying in current country. What actions I am likely to face?

Comment: https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/private_renting/how_to_end_a_fixed_term_tenancy_early

Answer (score 1):

When you say you "cancelled plans", does that mean you aren't even in the UK and have never taken possession of the property?

Or are you leaving early?

It's unlikely as a practical matter that you will owe the full year, unless there is some strange circumstance which means the property cannot be immediately re-let. The rental market is quite hot currently, so that is unlikely.

Once you've told the landlord that you are breaking the tenancy early and that you have left, or that you don't intend to take possession in the first place, then they are on notice to find and install another tenant.

If you do this with enough notice, you may end up owing nothing, or certainly too little for the landlord to chase you for.

If you are based out of the country, it is also unlikely for practical reasons that the landlord will attempt to chase, although it's worth thinking about whether this could ever cause you trouble in the future.